# code coverage with Azure DevOps and @web/test-runner

Tags: azure-devops, lit-element, lit

I'm using azure devops for me builds, and I'm trying to get code coverage reporting working. `@web/test-runner` outputs `lcov.info` and a `lcov-report` directory that contains html files.

I tried using `reportgenerator@5` to convert this to Cobertura format. This sort of works, but the resulting output in devops is just a high level view, you cannot see inside the javascript files. Also it doesn't report on src files that are not tested at all.

The relevant tasks in my azure pipeline:

```yaml
- script: npm run test
  displayName: 'unit tests'
- task: reportgenerator@5
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  displayName: Converting lcov to cobertura
  inputs:
    reports: 'coverage/lcov.info' 
    targetdir: 'coverage/'  
    reporttypes: 'Cobertura'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: 'coverage/Cobertura.xml'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-results.xml' 
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

First part of Cobertura.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage line-rate="0.6182993812139331" branch-rate="0.512396694214876" lines-covered="8893" lines-valid="14383" branches-covered="186" branches-valid="363" complexity="NaN" version="0" timestamp="1699906675">
  <sources />
  <packages>
    <package name="Default" line-rate="0.6182993812139331" branch-rate="0.512396694214876" complexity="NaN">
      <classes>
        <class name="src\***redacted***.js" filename="src\***redacted***.js" line-rate="0.9323467230443975" branch-rate="0.8181818181818182" complexity="NaN">
          <methods>
            <method name="get is" signature="" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="NaN">
              <lines>
                <line number="28" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="100% (1/1)" />
                <line number="29" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="30" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="31" hits="1" branch="false" />
              </lines>
            </method>
            <method name="get template" signature="" line-rate="1" branch-rate="1" complexity="NaN">
              <lines>
                <line number="32" hits="1" branch="true" condition-coverage="100% (1/1)" />
                <line number="33" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="34" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="35" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="36" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="37" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="38" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="39" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="40" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="41" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="42" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="43" hits="1" branch="false" />
                <line number="44" hits="1" branch="false" />
```

Code Coverage in DevOps:

[image: Code Coverage]

Any ideas/examples on how to solve this?

Comment: It's recommended to share the cobertura coverage.xml output file,  your reportgenerator@5 task definition, and screenshot of the report view, so we can be more clear on the details.

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft Thanks, I added more details. One reason that I found online about the click through not working is cobertura not containing classes, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: in your  Cobertura.xml, the `<source />` doesn't contain any source directory. Please add `sourcedirs: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'` for the `reportgenerator@5` to specify the source directory, you can check the details in [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator) for the usage.